# How to correct for a xshift in the pgfplot legend?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, legend

Using the following example code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
                xlabel=$x$,
                ylabel={$f(x) = x^2 - x +4$}
        ]
        % use TeX as calculator:
        \addplot {x^2 - x +4};
        \addlegendentry{First plot}
        \addplot [xshift=1cm]{x^2 - x +4};
        \addlegendentry{Second plot}
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Creates this chart with the strange legend:

[image: Broken legend]

I guess this is due to the xshift property for the plot, but how can I revert this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can revert this shift by shifting the "legend image" (i.e. the small plot extract that is drawn in the legend) back by the same distance. To do this, set the option `legend image post style={xshift=-1cm}` as an option to `\addplot`.

It should be pointed out that using `xshift` is not really the "proper" way to shift a plot, because it works on the wrong level (you just shift the path, not the "logical" plot). You should instead be adjusting the function: In this case, you should use `(x-1)^2 - (x-1) +4` instead of `x^2 - x +4`.

Another option is to use `x filter/.code=\pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult+1}` to manipulate the x-coordinate. This can come in handy if you want to shift the plot without changing the plot expression.

The code below shows all three approaches, also demonstrating the problem with the `xshift` approach:

[image: shifting things with PGFplots]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
                xlabel=$x$,
                ylabel={$f(x) = x^2 - x +4$}
        ]
        % use TeX as calculator:
        \addplot {x^2 - x +4};  \addlegendentry{First plot}
        \addplot +[xshift=1cm,legend image post style={xshift=-1cm}]{x^2 - x +4};  \addlegendentry{Second plot}
        \addplot {(x+1)^2 - (x+1) +4};  \addlegendentry[]{Third plot}
        \addplot +[x filter/.code=\pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult-2}] {(x+1)^2 - (x+1) +4};  \addlegendentry{Fourth plot}
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Jake, thanks for your answer! Your right, for this example you should change the formula, but it was just a small example I adapted to make a clear example. For my use case it's a small shift to plot 3 data sets (marks only) in the same chart.

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense! I've added a different way of shifting the plot that might be useful for your case